Unexpected order of execution for a single thread involving threading.Lock()
I have an app that creates threads for a particular instance, which would then convert a word document to pdf files. It looks like this
@app.route('/cont')
def create_pdf():
    
    id = request.args.get('id')
    logger.info(f"Received - ID: {id}")
    helper = threading.Thread(target=cont_helper,args=(id,))
    helper.start()
    return jsonify({"message": "Received"})


Now I use libreoffice to do the file conversion, but since libreoffice is apparently not thread safe I use an instance of threading.Lock().

conversion_lock = threading.Lock()


def convert_file_to_pdf(file_path):

    subprocess.run( f'libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf {file_path}', shell=True)
    
    pdf_file_path = f'{file_path.split(".")[0]}.pdf'
    return pdf_file_path



def cont_helper(id): 

.
.
.
   with conversion_lock:
       path_to_pdf = convert_file_to_pdf(target_path)
    
   logger.info(f"Path to pdf:{path_to_pdf}")
.
.
.
    

Multiple threads are created at the same time, but doesn't have any shared resource except for the conversion with libreoffice.
Now the issue according to log file is, for example, thread A does the conversion and that would mean that it has acquired the lock and then prints the pdf path,  but sometimes another thread prints the path to the pdf without having attempted the conversion at all. What could possibly be causing this outcome?

I get that. That is why I am trying to lock the code where the conversion happens.

Looks like maybe you forgot to indent
   with conversion_lock:
       path_to_pdf = convert_file_to_pdf(target_path)
    
       logger.info(f"Path to pdf:{path_to_pdf}")

The last line.

How would not including that in the critical section change the sequence of execution within a thread? The thread should wait to acquire the lock if it is not available and not execute the code after the critical section.

You probably want to print the locked path not some other path you do not have control over.
